# How can I concat a string into a JSON call?

Tags: javascript, json

I'll try and makes this succinct.
My JSON data reads:

```
  "brand":{

   "active" : "brand1",

   "brand1" : {
    "bodyColour" : "#f2f2f2",
    "logoClickthroughURL" : "#"
   },

   "brand2" : {
    "bodyColour" : "#f2f2f2",
    "logoClickthroughURL" : "#"
   }

  }
```

I want to access the brand bodyColour and logoClickthroughURL based on what is active.

I've tried this:

```
var activeBrand = brand.active;
var activeBodyColour = brand.activeBrand.bodyColour;
```

This fires an error. I've tried to concat with "+" but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks, All.

Moe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use square brackets:

`var activeBodyColour = brand[activeBrand].bodyColour`

The reason dot notation doesn't work is it is looking for a key that is literally called 'activeBrand'.  Bracket notation allows you to access a property using a variable key name.